# How to exclude data source dependency before building the JAR file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have a library with different dependencies, and I want to exclude/ignore all data source dependencies when I introduce this library in my API.

I know that I can easily ignore dependencies in my API by using exclude:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})`

But how do I do that on the "Gradle" level, how do I do that in my library before building the JAR file and before using it in my API?

Comment: To better understand your question. Do you have to cases 1) with the datasource dependencies and one without or 2) you just want to exclude the datasource dependencies from the fat jar?

Comment: 2, I just want to exclude the data source dependencies from the fat jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for me was to use:

```
compileOnly 'org.example'
testImplementation 'org.example'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the appropriate scope.

Read more about scopes: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html

Comment: Do you mean that I should define a custom configuration?

Comment: You should use a scope like compileOnly then the dependency will not be in the JAR

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean but I tried that, and unfortunately, I can't build the jar because of database-related errors.

Comment: I also tried to add this in build.gradle: `configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
}`

The library will build but the project will still have a data source dependency.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do